# Python - Count letters in random strings

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a bunch of integers which are allocated values using the random module, then converted to letters depending on their position of the alphabet.

I then combine a random sample of these variables into a "master" variable, which is printed to the console.

I want to then count the occurrence of each character, which will later be written to an output file.

Any help on how i would go about doing this?

Comment: Can you show us what you have so far, and where the problem is?

Comment: Hey @Klicker, can you show us your code, please? -1 for the lack of efforts in writing a proper question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> for letter, count in Counter("aaassd").items():
...     print("letter", letter, "count", count)
... 
letter s count 2
letter a count 3
letter d count 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably better to use `collections.Counter()`, but here is a list comprehension

```
>>> li = 'aaassd'
>>> res = {ch: sum(1 for x in li if x==ch) for ch in set(li)}
{'d': 1, 's': 2, 'a': 3}
```